# Trying to create a script that triggers on a folder creation event within the Google Drive App

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm a super novice when it comes to Javascript, but anyway, here is my problem.

Whenever a New folder is created in google drive I want to automatically create a subfolder. The easiest way I can think of doing this is use some sort of onEvent trigger within app scripts. But I can't figure out if it is possible to do a "onNewFolder" trigger (or whatever it might be named).

It should be easy If I could I could simply use that trigger ---> i.e. when a new file is created automatically "createFolder(name)"

Hopefully that makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

You need to setup Push Notifications for the folder or file using Google's Drive API. Below is a link to documentation on the feature:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/push

Unfortunately Google Apps Script has limitations that will prevent you from using it effectively. Typically you'd deploy a script as a Web App and use its URL as a web hook endpoint to receive push notifications via POST. However, Drive Push Notifications sends all of its pertinent information as request headers, which cannot be accessed from Google Apps Script at the moment.

I came up with a solution that leverages Cloud Functions as a go-between to get around those limits. I wrote an article about this approach at the following link:

https://gist.github.com/DimuDesigns/7b49c9fe4de79f851fbeaa4cb18d0126

There is a feature request on google's issue tracker that requests support for request headers for Apps Script Web Apps.

Please lend your support by starring the issue at the link below:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67764685

Comment: hi, I would be interested by your solution, however the G+ link isn't working anymore

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the [G Suite Activity API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/activity/).

> The Activity API consists of the Activity resource, which represents changes made to objects within a user's Google Drive, and the list method, which allows you to retrieve information about those changes.

Here's an [API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/activity/v1/reference/activities/list). Here's the [Javascript sample code](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/activity/v1/quickstart/js)  to get you started.

Comment: Thanks! I will look into all this! Never saw the G suite Activity API

Comment: AFAIK the Activity API works for changes, not for creation of new objects on a user's Google Drive.

Comment: @Rubén If you look farther down on the page of the API Explorer (middle column) you'll see a table row whose first column is `activities[].combinedEvent.primaryEventType` whose _Acceptable values_ include `create` and `move` among others

Comment: Have you find the how to listen to the create new folder event?

Comment: @Rubén Honestly, no. At the moment, I'm thinking the client has to poll the server.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) either an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) for new folders.

The alternative is to create a time-driven trigger that looks for new folders. Unfortunatelly the [Google Drive Search Parameters](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters) doesn't include one to search by creation time, so your script should scan all folders and compare the date returned by [getDateCreated()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getdatecreated) with the last date that the script ran.