# Script Trigger when user open a folder in Google Drive

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, triggers, google-drive-api, shared-directory

I want a basic script to protect folders in Google Drive folders structure. When the users try to access a folder called "Private", for example, i want shows an alert or prompt to entry a password.

If users known the password, they can access into the folder. But if the password its not okay, they won't access never.

I want to make it with Google Apps Script.

Anybody can help me?

Comment: Related: [Trying to create a script that triggers on a folder creation event within the Google Drive App](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48102195/1595451)

Comment: Removed the "something like" part as it make the question prone to be closed as asking for external resources which is off-topic on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible. There is no such trigger or function exists to do something like this.

Why not just share the folder with the selected users and then they will need to log into Google to open it?

Comment: Oh! :(
I want to have a full structure with a root folder. But not all can access to all subfolders.. For this reason I wanted make that..

The folders in Google Drive should be protected with password.. :(

Comment: They are protected with a password if you share the folder with people then they can access it.  If you create a shared folder 'root' and share it with x, y and z then they can access it and all subfolders by default. If you have a subfolder 'pictures' and you only want x & y to access it then go to 'share' - 'advanced' and remove y form the list. This is a close as you will get, unfortunately. I haven't checked but there could be a request in for this already.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to protect a Google Drive folder with a password. The way to protect them is by using or not using the sharing function.

By the other hand there isn't a [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) either an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) for folders events like create, open or close.